# Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm working with Room persistance databases in android but i get this error 
**error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    test.android.orca.com.ws2db.Models.User... user);**
Please help me

**This is my DAO :**

```
@Dao
abstract interface UserDao
{
@get:Query("SELECT * FROM user")
val getall: List<User>

@Query("SELECT * FROM user where name LIKE  :name AND login LIKE :login")
fun findByName(name: String, login: String): User

@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from user")
fun countUsers(): Int

@Insert
fun insertAll(users: List<User>)

@Delete
fun delete(vararg user: User)
}
```

**This is my Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
class UserTable {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var uid: Int = 0

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
var name: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "login")
var login: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
var id: Int = 0

@ColumnInfo(name="url")
var url: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name="company")
var company:String?=null

}
```

**Database**

```
@Database(entities = [UserTable::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

companion object {

    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, 
             AppDatabase::class.java, "user-database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
        }
        return INSTANCE
    }

    fun destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null
    }
}}
```

This is the error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnECR.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `user` and `UserTable`. `User` is valid for referencing your table, but your entity is `UserTable`

```
@Dao
abstract interface UserDao
{
@get:Query("SELECT * FROM user")
val getall: List<UserTable>

@Query("SELECT * FROM user where name LIKE  :name AND login LIKE :login")
fun findByName(name: String, login: String): UserTable

@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from user")
fun countUsers(): Int

@Insert
fun insertAll(users: List<UserTable>)

@Delete
fun delete(vararg user: UserTable)
}
```

Comment: val getall: List<User> also should be val getall: List<UserTable> ?

Comment: Glad to help. However, let me advise you to change some names. It's better to change `UserTable` to `User_entity` and `user` to `user_table`. I think it's more readable.

Comment: So, If I want to use model converter to entity by typeConverter How can I do that? Example, When I have a UserEntity and UserModel, I can want to save UserModel, And I want to converting by Model to Entity by @TypeConverter. In this case, compiler is throwing "Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity"